# Why doesnt the automatic updates work in xubuntu 19.10?

Tags: updates, xubuntu, 19.10, unattended-upgrades, automatic

I cant get the automatic updates to work in Xubuntu 19.10. Even though the options in software and updates is set to download and install automatically in the background they never download. I open up the software updater and it offers to install stuff that doesnt install at all on its own.

Answer (score 2):

`unattended-upgrades` by default is only set up to install security patches. Regular updates are still up to you, and will pop up in the GUI or list when you run `sudo apt update`.

This doesn't necessarily mean that `unattended-upgrades` is not running properly.

Comment: It's not installing the security updates either. And the GUI doesnt pop up automatically(It only pops up when I select it from the menu. I did try sudo apt update and that just tells me I have packages to upgrade.

Comment: I think I figured out what was going wrong. Upon looking in the logs of unattended-upgrades it said it was aborting because I'm on a metered connection. (lately I've been tethering to my phone) I also noticed in network settings for the connection I can select metered connection (No) instead of automatic. I think that may fix it for the future.

Comment: Excellent, I hope this solves your problem!